# How to validate response value containing the number sign #

Tags: karate

My response looks like this:

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TEST FORMAT",
    "value": "#####"
  }
]

I want to validate it like this:
And match response[0] == { id: 1, name: 'TEST FORMAT', value: '#####' }

But it gives me the error below:
ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: $[0].value, actual: '#####', expected: '#####', reason: unknown validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Karate treats strings that start with `#` as special and 99% of the time you won't be affected by it.

Anyway, here is the workaround:

```
* def response = [ { "id": 1, "name": "TEST FORMAT", "value": "#####" } ]
* match response[0] == { id: 1, name: 'TEST FORMAT', value: '#? _ == "#####"' }
* match response[0] == { id: 1, name: 'TEST FORMAT', value: '#regex #{5}' }
```

I'm actually fixing this right now so that it should work as expected in future versions without needing the workaround.

Comment: Great, the workaround works.  But I'll wait for the fix.

Comment: @bhc you can try 0.7.0.RC2 which is available now.

Comment: I tried RC2 and it worked.  Thank you for your prompt resolution.